# tinymce disable and enable editor and show text (not as html)

Tags: tinymce

I have 2 editors inside my page. when i click a button i want them to become disabled.

If it is possible i would like it to become a regular textarea and to see the text inise of it as a regular text and not html.

I saw other questions for disabling but did not get them to work..

This is my code:

```
function create_text_editor()
    {
            $('#remarks1').tinymce(
            {
                    script_url : 'resources/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                    theme : "advanced",
                    theme_advanced_buttons1 :         "cut,copy,paste,|,bold,italic,underline,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|" ,
                    theme_advanced_buttons2 :         "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|",
                    theme_advanced_buttons3 :         "",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align :    "left",
                    plugins :                         "paste" ,               
                    oninit : on_editor_init                                       });

             $('#remarks2').tinymce(
            {
                    script_url : 'resources/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                    theme : "advanced",
                    theme_advanced_buttons1 :         "cut,copy,paste,|,bold,italic,underline,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|" ,
                    theme_advanced_buttons2 :         "formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|",
                    theme_advanced_buttons3 :         "",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align :    "left",
                    plugins :                         "paste" ,                 
                    oninit : on_editor_init                });
    }
```

'on_editor_init' is emtpy.

Any help will be appritiated,

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call the save function and to shutdown tinymce. Of course you can execute this code when pushing a tinymce UI button (i guess you know how that works)

```
tinymce.get(editor_id).save();

tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, editor_id);
```

Now, you should be able to see the textarea that has been on the website before initializing tinymce.